# ClassisThesis: beramono option has no effect

Tags: classicthesis, beramono

I am using the ClassisThesis style back and set the typewriter font to beramono, according to the [ClassisThesis manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/ClassicThesis.pdf). But I can't see any change in the resulting pdf. Do I miss something?

`\usepackage[
beramono,
]{classicthesis}`

The package with and without beromono is running, but sounds like the font were an advantage.

It is compiled with pdflatex (xelatex works as well). The example I used is the clas­sic­the­sis-book.tex from [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/Examples). System is 12.04 with ClassisThesis 2011/12/17 v4.0 and texlive 2012 from PPA.

a short working example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[beramono]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I also wanted to ask for an MWE, but a question that is burning under my nails is: Are you using a monospaced font in your document?

Comment: you should also update your texlive installation, that's a rather old one!

Comment: The `beramono` option only affects text in `\ttfamily` (or `\texttt`). If you don't use those commands you can't see any difference.

Comment: @Johannes_B: when I understand you correctly, monospaced is NOT the main font in a document. I guess, my answer is no then. For which parts is it relevant? So their is no switch for the main font in ClassicThesis?

Answer (score 2):

The `beramono` option only affects the monospaced font. Here's the result of typesetting the following example

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[beramono]{classicthesis}
%\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

This is the normal font

\texttt{this is monospaced: \fontname\font}

\end{document}
```

First with the option `beramono` enabled

[image]

Then with the option disabled

[image]

Comment: You busy bee :-)